# Which Laptop is best for Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have system with 2gb ram and core i5 processor.Is it compatible with android studio.Which one will be the best system for android studio.

**Problems Faced in my curent system**

1.I find my gradle build really slow.
2.During starting of emulator on console error is coming that is related to heap size.

**Solution i tried**

1.Update Android sdk tools
2.From bin folder changed the maximum size to 1024m and minimum to 256m

Still facing the problem and Its taking too much time.

If its an system issue then please provide me a laptop name with proper system requirements within 60k.

Thanks
Pranap

Comment: Laptop??? Really????

Comment: My system have 12/16GB ram to make it running my development smoothly. You should look for at-least 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should add some more RAM to your system.

It's not a config solution, you're facing hardware limitations, so I'll really recommend you to upgrade your system up to 8gb RAM.It's a really cheap invest and it will improve your working time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your hardisk to SSD also.
Which helps to improve performance of your laptop around 40-50% faster.
You can look here for new laptop check below link
https://yourchoicestore.in/?s=i5+laptop